# crm 2011 date format in trial system

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have tried to create 30-day trial systems specifying a region outside of the US so that the date format would be dd/mm/yyyy.

The trial system is always created with a US date format.

I have tried changing this format in Administration->System Settings, but my changes there don't seem to have any impact.

This has only been the case since I have needed to create Office365 accounts - up to then it was ok.

Answer (score 2):

You should also check the users personal settings.

1. Log on as the user
2. Open Crm
3. Click File (blue button, top left)
4. Click Options
5. Click Formats
6. Confirm the 'Current Format' is correct.

Comment: That's great - it worked. Can't believe I didn't check that out! It seems that the new way they have of creating users (i.e. making them Office 365 users) changes the way the default settings are set - maybe.